# producer.close() does not execute the code afterwards

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am facing a strange issue in my producer code for kafka

```
producer.flush();
logger.info("Closing producer");
producer.close();
logger.info("successfully closed producer");
```

I have above code snippet as part of a code, the problem is that I am only able to see the following output

```
Closing producer
```

in my logs the last line does not appear.
If I comment out producer.close() it does appear in logs.
Any ideas why this is so?

Answer (score 0):

What is the name of the topic on the producer? I asked, because as far as i know there is a currently open [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3018) that block the client thread if the topic name contains single quotes. Can you check that?

Comment: The topic name is test. It  doesn't have any special characters